# Причастный и сравнительный оборот

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, будет ли входить сравнительный оборот "как я" в состав причастного оборота "обманутые так же" и подчёркиваться одной волнистой линией? Или это рассматривать в отдельности?

***...Мне непременно встречались русские, обманутые так же, как я... (А. П. Чехов)***

Answer (score 1):

Да, сопоставительный оборот будет входить в причастный оборот, так как без него причастный оборот не имеет какого-либо законченного смысла. Иначе и быть не может.

Comment: «ДА» на какой вопрос отвечает, что утверждает или подтверждает? Чем подтвердите вывод «иначе и быть не может»?

Comment: На какой вопрос отвечает «да»? Вы не читали мое сообщение после слова «да»? Причастный оборот должен содержать завершенную смысловую характеристику, которую он дает определяемому слову неким сочетанием слов. Без сопоставительного оборота причастный оборот не имеет завершенного смысла либо не имеет того смысла, который нужен автору. Я видел массу примеров, когда в определительный оборот входили другие обособленные сочетания слов. Вот, например, вводное слово внутри причастного оборота: «Здесь росли сказочные дубы, знавшие, быть может, Пушкина.

Comment: Будет ли сравнительный оборот? — спрашивают. Не находите странным, что в ответе видим: «Да, сопоставительный оборот будет.»?

Comment: Это одно и тоже.